# Microsoft Graph api create calendar but ErrorAccessDenied?

Tags: calendar, microsoft-graph-calendar

[image]

[image]

Please help me? I want create calendar with Microsoft graph but I received error:

> "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
> "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."

Please tell me why.